# C# datagridview two checkboxes columns act like two radio buttons

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

i'm developing an application using c# i've add two checkboxes in the datagridview. i want them to act like two radio buttons. if first checkbox is checked the other one is unchecked automatically
i tried some code but did't work for me.

```
private void datagridSB_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 15)
        {

            if (Convert.ToBoolean(datagridSB.CurrentRow.Cells[15].Value)==true)
            {
                datagridSB.CurrentRow.Cells[17].Value = false;
                //uncheck the second checkbox
            }
            else if (Convert.ToBoolean(datagridSB.CurrentRow.Cells[15].Value)==false)
            {
                datagridSB.CurrentRow.Cells[17].Value = true;
                //check the second checkbox
            }
        }
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 17)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(datagridSB.CurrentRow.Cells[17].Value) == true)
            {
                datagridSB.CurrentRow.Cells[15].Value = false;
                //uncheck the first checkbox
            }
            else if (Convert.ToBoolean(datagridSB.CurrentRow.Cells[17].Value) == false)
            {
                datagridSB.CurrentRow.Cells[15].Value = true;
                //check the first checkbox 
            }
        }   
    }
```

i get the error NullReferenceException was un handled (object reference not set to an instance of an object)
any help please

Comment: I assume this grid is databound? If so, make changes to the source, not the grid.

Comment: No it's not. It's justa blank datagridview with some columns that user should input the data and on button save click data should be saved at once

Comment: Ok, when you put breakpoints in, is your expected change happening?  And if not, what is failing?

Comment: I know the code should be in CellValueChanged but when i do the same code in the CellValueChanged i get an error (object reference not set to an instance of an object)

Comment: It's not reconizing the condition. It always go where the condition=true even if i uncheck the checkbox it goes where it says true

Comment: You should check to make sure `datagridSB.CurrentRow.Cells[17].Value` is not null before you try to convert it. `If (datagridSB.CurrentRow.Cells[17].Value == null)` then the check box is not checked and will throw an error (as you are getting) if you try to convert this null value. This seems odd to use two check boxes when only one is needed.

Comment: @JohnG i tried still through the same error

Comment: The posted code does not show this. It appears you are still trying to convert a possible null value with lines: `Convert.ToBoolean(datagridSB.CurrentRow.Cells[15].Value)` AND `Convert.ToBoolean(datagridSB.CurrentRow.Cells[17].Value`. I will have to take your word for this, as the posted code will still fail if this condition arises.

Comment: @JohnG i tried if(datagridSB.CurrentRow.Cells[15].Value==null){msgbx("0");}else{msgbx("1");} but i still get the same error before even the form is loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private void datagridSB_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (datagridSB.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "withCashSB")
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell buttonCell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)datagridSB.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["withProCSB"];

            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell checkCell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)datagridSB.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["withCashSB"];
            buttonCell.Value = !(Boolean)checkCell.Value;
            datagridSB.Invalidate();
        }
        else if (datagridSB.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "withProCSB")
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell buttonCell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)datagridSB.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["withCashSB"];

            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell checkCell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)datagridSB.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["withProCSB"];
            buttonCell.Value = !(Boolean)checkCell.Value;
            datagridSB.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void datagridSB_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (datagridSB.IsCurrentCellDirty)
        {
            datagridSB.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
        }
    }
```

here is the answer to make two check boxes acts like two radio buttons ..

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe I missed it, sec... You are converting to bool the entire condition:

```
Convert.ToBoolean(datagridSB.CurrentRow.Cells[17].Value = true)
```

move the end paren to after the value, and == not "=" in C#  so:

```
Convert.ToBoolean(datagridSB.CurrentRow.Cells[17].Value) == true
```

Your code is setting the value, and evaluating your boolean off the set...

Comment: It didn't work but now it goes where the condition = false. I tried the same code on the CellValueChanged event n i still get the error (object reference not set to an instance of an object)

Comment: Ok, so what part is null? My guess is CurrentRow.

Comment: Yeah, it's the currentRow. Line

Comment: My pleasure, if you could mark this as answered, it would be appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I still do not understand why you want to use two check boxes when one appears to be all that is needed. The problem you may run into is twofold. First, using the `CurrentRow` property of the `DataGridView` is risky, it may return unexpected results and I feel this may be one of the problems. The other issue is using the `CellValueChanged` event to capture when the user changes one of the check boxes. This event appears to return false in some cases when the check box is checked. Because of this odd behavior, I am guessing the `CellValueChanged` event is not the best for what you want to do.

To remedy these two issues, I recommend you use the `RowIndex` returned from the event instead of the `CurrentRow` property. Also, the event we want to change to is the `CellContentClick` event. This event will fire when the user clicks into the content of a cell. In the case of the check box cells, this will change its value from checked to un-checked and vice versa. Here we simply need to check if the check box is checked. If it is checked, then set the other check box to un-checked and vice –versa.

The code below demonstrates what is described above. There is a `DataGridView` with three columns, the last two columns are check boxes. The `CellContentClick` event is wired up to capture when the content of a cell is clicked then we simply check to see if the cell clicked is in columns 1 or 2, then set the other check box appropriately. I added the `CellContentDoubleClick` event to call the `CellContentClick` event, otherwise the user would be able to quickly double click on a check box and not give time for the other checkbox to get set, resulting in both check boxes with the same value.

```
private void datagridSB_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  int curRow = e.RowIndex;
  if (e.ColumnIndex == 1) {
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cbc = datagridSB.Rows[curRow].Cells[1] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
    bool isChecked = (bool)cbc.EditedFormattedValue;
    if (isChecked) {
      datagridSB.Rows[curRow].Cells[2].Value = false;
    } else {
      datagridSB.Rows[curRow].Cells[2].Value = true;
    }
  }
  if (e.ColumnIndex == 2) {
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cbc = datagridSB.Rows[curRow].Cells[2] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
    bool isChecked = (bool)cbc.EditedFormattedValue;
    if (isChecked) {
      datagridSB.Rows[curRow].Cells[1].Value = false;
    } else {
      datagridSB.Rows[curRow].Cells[1].Value = true;
    }
  }
}

private void datagridSB_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  datagridSB_CellContentClick(sender, e);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you it was very helpful. it helped me solving the question :)